# Plotly: Plotly express area chart with a single color for fill and line

Tags: python, colors, plotly

Hi i try to figure out how to use just one color per country - filled color. The following example gives a mix of transparent and a darker color per country. i expect just one color. Thanks for help

```
import plotly
#import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.area(df, x="year", y="pop", color="country",
          groupnorm='fraction')
plotly.io.write_image(fig, file='areatest.png', format='png')
```

Comment: I don't think there is a plotly.express to control the fill. This is a no-fill setting.`fig.update_traces(fill='none')` Kindly refer to [this](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-fill).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no `px.area` attribute that will give you a single color directly. But that should not stop you. Just use:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda trace: trace.update(fillcolor = trace.line.color))
```

... to get:

[image]

... instead of the default result which is:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
df = df[df['continent']=='Americas']
fig = px.area(df, x="year", y="pop", color="country",
          groupnorm='fraction')
fig.for_each_trace(lambda trace: trace.update(fillcolor = trace.line.color))
fig.show()
```

#### Some details:

`px.area` will assign a color to each line associated with the `color` argument, and then apply a partially transparent version of that color to the corresponding area / fill. If you run `fig.show` you can check the color for the first category:

```
Scatter({
    'fillcolor': '#636efa',
    'groupnorm': 'fraction',
    'hovertemplate': 'country=Argentina<br>year=%{x}<br>pop=%{y}<extra></extra>',
    'legendgroup': 'Argentina',
    'line': {'color': '#636efa'},
```

Here you can only see that `'line': {'color': '#636efa'}` and it can undoubtedly be a bit confusing that fillcolor is nowhere to be found . But if you use `fig.full_figure_for_development`, you can see that the fillcolor that is in fact passed to javascript is `'rgba(99, 110, 250, 0.5)'`:

```
Scatter({
    'connectgaps': False,
    'error_x': {'visible': False},
    'error_y': {'visible': False},
    'fill': 'tonexty',
    'fillcolor': 'rgba(99, 110, 250, 0.5)',
```

And that's exactly what you're overriding when you run:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda trace: trace.update(fillcolor = trace.line.color))
```

Comment: wow, a super easy solution to implement, thank you!!! looks like you are really familiar with plotly.